# weird behavior in Knockout.js compute function

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code in an app using Knockout.js, but something got my attention with the following function:

```
this.filterLocations = ko.computed(function () {
                    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations(), function (loc) {
                        if(self.textFilter() != undefined){
                            self.hideMarkers();
                            return loc.title.toLowerCase().includes(self.textFilter().toLowerCase());
                        }else{
                            return true;
                        }

                    });
                }, this);
```

I would like to call the `self.hideMarkers()` in the else statement but when I use it inside the else statement I got the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: self.hideMarkers is not a function

I can't figure out why this is happening because the same call in the if statement doesn't have any error and work fine.

The function code is:

```
this.hideMarkers = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.markers.length; i++) {
            var isIn = true;
            for (var y = 0; y < self.filterLocations().length; y++) {
                var el = self.filterLocations()[y];
                if(el.id !== i + 1 ){
                    isIn = false;
                }else{
                    isIn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isIn){
                self.markers[i].setMap(map);
            }else{
                self.markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
    };
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: Not sure what the actual problem is, but it looks to me like you're doing all kinds of things *inside* your filter method that should be happening outside...

Comment: Yes, because in this case I have list of items showed and also a list of markers so the filter function needs to return a boolean to filter the list but also call the method to filter the markers in the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem calling directly:

```
self.filterLocations = ko.computed(function () {
                    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locations(), function (loc) {
                        if(self.textFilter() == undefined || self.textFilter() == ""){
                            for (var i = 0; i < self.markers.length; i++) {
                                self.markers[i].setMap(map);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        self.hideMarkers();
                        return loc.title.toLowerCase().includes(self.textFilter().toLowerCase());
                    });
                }, this);
```

But this still a weird behavior.